# how do i insert html code after a class or id in Prototype js?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, insertafter

Actually I want to insert some html code after an id or class. This is my code:

```
$$(".validation-advice").each( function (val,i) {
            x = val.innerHTML;
            val.remove();
});
```

In jQuery would be smth like this `$( x ).insertAfter( ".myclass" );`, but i don't know what is the equivalent to this in prototype. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: there's an extra $ but I'm sure it's a typo!

Comment: not there is not, thats how i traverse all of the classes with the specificied name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution: `$('myid').insert({after: x});`